# qmail is returning all mails as "handlers permanentfail"

Tags: linux, email, domainkeys

i am sending emails through php and qmail
with SPF record and domainkeys on.
but all emails are returned as handlers permanentfail.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this by any chance a Plesk server? There's a handful of reports of this found via Googling. Here's one purported fix:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mchk --with-spam
```